# How can I check username and password of an existing user in WordPress with react-native/

Tags: wordpress, react-native, authentication

I'm writing a mobile application for a WordPress site.
I want to check username and password with WPAPI and JSON Basic Authentication plugin.
I have tried this code so far:

```
  const wp = new WPAPI({
    endpoint: 'https://example.com/wp-json',
    username: this.state.username,
    password: this.state.password
  });
  console.log(wp.users().me());
```

it returns

> _options:{auth:true, ...}

no matter what is the username and password value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally solved this problem:

```
 validate() {
  let username = this.state.username;
  let password = this.state.password;
  let userPassCombination = username + ':' + password;
  let encodedPass = base64.encode(userPassCombination);

  let headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'text/json',
    Authorization: 'Basic ' + encodedPass,
  };

  fetch(myConstants.URL + '/wp-json/', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: headers,
  }).then(responseData => {
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(responseData));
    if (responseData.ok) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile', {
        username: this.state.username,
      });
    } 
    else {
      alert('wrong information.');
    }
  });
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Maybe show your react native implementation of the WPAPI.

> **[Documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wpapi#api-query-parameters):**
>
> *As an example, wp.users().me() will automatically enable authentication to permit access to the /users/me endpoint.*

Sounds like it's more an API-Call which set a flag instead of returning your userprofile (I guess you expected to get your user-profile?!)

Maybe give it a try to request a page (like described in the examples (see: [Documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wpapi#api-query-parameters))):
`wp.pages().slug( 'about' )`

Comment: it didn't work. still I get **_options:{auth:true, ...}**  no matter what is the username and password.

Comment: I have also tried using fetch:   fetch('https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2', {
       headers: new Headers({
       Authorization: `Basic ${base64.encode(
           `${this.state.username}:${this.state.password}`
          )}`,
        }),
      }).then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) alert('Error');
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
      }); but it didn't work.